# create a mapping values for node roles

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

my values file has a nodeRole as key value pair however my deployment file throws an error as it can only only accept string and not mapping values. How do I fix this?

values.yaml :

```
 nodeRoles:
          key: 
          value:
```

deployment.yaml:

```
nodeSelector:   
    nodeRoles:
          key: {{.Values.nodeRoles.key}}
          value: {{.Values.nodeRoles.value}}
```

How do I make this work? I only want the deployment to accept key value pair and not string

Answer (score 0):

Tried Node affinity and it worked!

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).